# Image is not loading correctly in .net maui

Tags: c#, android, maui

I'm working on a simple image converter project and I have the following code that should load an image that is passed as a parameter.
The image path is this "/storage/emulated/0/Download/Image Converter/Png Images/IMG_20230219_134526.png" and yes, the image exists in the specified location. So much so that I can display this image in the .net maui Image control.
The code that should load the image for conversion is this:

```
private void ConvertImage(string imagePath, string pathSave, ImageFormat format)
{
  Microsoft.Maui.Graphics.IImage image;
  Assembly assembly = GetType().GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
  using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(imagePath))
  {
      image = PlatformImage.FromStream(stream);
  }
}
```

The problem is that the image is not loading correctly. See the image below and this has generated an exception when saving the image after conversion.

[image]

How do I solve this problem?`enter code here`

Comment: Code will not run on windows.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/graphics/images?view=net-maui-7.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GetManifestResourceStream` loads a **resource**, not a **file**.  They are not the same thing.  Use `File.Open` to return a `stream` from a **file path**